# ValueError: buffer is smaller than requested size when trying to read a .dta file

Tags: python, type-conversion, buffer, valueerror

dta files I want to convert to csv from .dta as I don't have Stata which is normally used to open the files. When trying to write the file into a variable on opening it I get the error:

ValueError: buffer is smaller than requested size

Can somebody please assist. Here is my code:
`import pandas as pd data = pd.read_stata(r"D:\Wave 1\Child_W1_Anon_V7.0.0.dta") df=pd.DataFrame(data) print(df)`

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me when I was uploading the .dta file. If you have an error in uploading the .dta file or you are trying to reading the file .dta file with pandas while the file is uploading, then you may get this error.